# Replace data from command line: site name

Tags: 6, database, drush

I run in mysql:

```
update variable set value = replace(value,'SiteName','NewName');
```

and then clearing cache:

```
drush cache-clear
```

But I dont know why the site name become blank instead of `NewName`

I've tried this after replace in variable table, but not works:

```
update cache set data = replace(data,'SiteName','NewName');
```

I hope I can change any data from command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values are serialized using the built in PHP function [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) so setting them directly shouldn't work if I understand what you did correctly. You can use drush since it appears you have that available.

Simply use:

```
drush variable-set site_name "Some name here"
```

Otherwise you can always configure from the Drupal admin interface.